# Tensorflow 2.0: Can I change the settings on a Tf.data.Dataset -- in particular the `repeat()` feature?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a tensorflow 2.0 `tf.data.Dataset` created from some pandas data. Now I wanted to change a setting on the dataset, but it seems to not let me do that. Case in point, I wanted to change the `.repeat()` parameter on the dataset from repeat infinitely, to repeat only 1 time. But when I tried to make this change, the Dataset did not accept the change.

Here is an example with some code. The function is taken from one of the Tensorflow Tutorials on the TF website.

```
URL = 'https://storage.googleapis.com/applied-dl/heart.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(URL)

def df_to_dataset(dataframe, shuffle=True, batch_size=32):
    dataframe = dataframe.copy()
    labels = dataframe.pop('target')
    ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(dataframe), labels))
    if shuffle:
        ds = ds.shuffle(buffer_size=len(dataframe))
    ds = ds.batch(batch_size).repeat() # <-- NOTICE THE INFINITE REPEAT
    return ds

train_ds = df_to_dataset(df)
train_ds.repeat(1) # <-- TRYING TO CHANGE TO A FIXED NUMBER OF REPETITIONS
```

So I tried to change the number of repeats on the Dataset, but this leads to a dataset that still repeats forever. It is like the if I were to set the dataset to repeat infinitely and then repeat 1 time, that I end up with a dataset that repeats infinitely, but 1 time--which is the same as repeating infinitely.

I imagine that the same behavior is probably true for other features of a dataset, such as the number of batches, or such.

Is there a way to reset the behavior on a dataset?

Comment: Why don't you put `ds = ds.repeat(n_epoch)` before `ds = ds.batch(batch_size)`.

Comment: @AnshKumar I could do something like that. But I think the question is really about overriding the behavior or settings of the tf.data.Dataset(). It is not clear from the documentation whether methods like `repeat()` or `batch()` mutate the Dataset in-place, or whether the Dataset object is lazy evaluated, and the settings are only applied when the Dataset is used in training.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the intended behavior. Once it is a dataset which repeats infinitely, repeat itself one more time still produce a dataset with infinite examples.

You probably could do `dataset.take(count)` though where `count` is the number that equals to the number of batches your original examples provided that you have a good shuffling of your data.

Comment: Yeah this is kinda my sense of it. It does seem odd that you cannot change this type of behavior. In my simple mind the Dataset api is just a generator for the data or batches. So users should be able to change the settings on the generator--especially before it is used by the `fit` function. The other confusing thing is that this immutable behavior seems at odds with the keras model API, where the `fit()` function lets the user configure **batches** even if the Dataset already has batches configured on it.